# Using Azure AD UserInfo.UniqueId for lookups?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

Will the Azure AD UserInfo.UniqueId property always have the same value coming out of the Azure AD instance?

Once a user is Authenticated via Azure what can I use to fetch the roles and privs from our side (we have an existing structure). Since we don't have a password, I was thinking that we could store the Unique Id of the Azure AD User and look up the roles and privs that way....thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UniqueId is sourced from the "best" identifier we receive from the service. In the most common case today that is the ObjectId of the user - which can indeed be used for retrieving more info. Please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog for more info on the queries you can perform.